# Fill RelativeLayout parent with LinearLayout child

Tags: android, android-layout

This seems simple but I've exhausted my Google search patience.

I have a `RelativeLayout` that has two sub `LinearLayout`s side-by-side and I want them both to vertically fill the parent, no matter the height of the two LinearLayouts. This is being used as a `ListView` row and the content under **@id/item_left** is generally shorter than the one on the right.

The background drawable doesn't fill the entire row.

Any ideas on making both sides fill?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_left"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/item_left_text"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/item_right_background"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_left">           
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/item_right_text"
            android:text="Row1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/item_right_text"
            android:text="Row2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/item_right_text"
            android:text="Row3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you want to give half-half width to both ?

Comment: The width is just to flow with the content. Left side is much less width than the right.

Comment: so you need to Left  width as per content but both LL must fill the parent finally?

Comment: Correct, both to vertically fill.

Comment: your layout should work if you don't want the two LinearLayouts with the same size, the solution is similar to yours except changing a relative layout to a linear one!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code .... sorry but I changed the color to so the impact when you will change the text of first  TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff" android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dp" android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:background="#ff0000ff" android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/time" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ff555555"
            android:text="sdfdsf s ada d a   asd sad sad"  />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffff0000" 
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ff555555"
            android:text="Row1" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ff00ff00"
            android:text="Row2" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ff00ff00"
            android:text="Row3" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However `layout_toRightOf` doesn't exist for a child of a `LinearLayout` and also `layout_weight` doesn't exist for a child of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: yup but not looks "android:layout_toRightOf" is required their as LinearLayout will automatically add that in the right in android:orientation="horizontal" (which is default one)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="helloooooooooooooo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout1"
        android:background="#0000FF"

 >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this and it makes one row the entire screen, but nothing displays.